# Python Scripting for Abaqus

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I am new to Abaqus Python Scripting. The following line of code in my script is throwing a keyword error (`Type Error: Keyword error on mergeWire`).

```
myPart.WirePolyLine(points = myPoints, mergeWire = OFF, meshable = ON)
```

where

```
myPoints = ((datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[0]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[1]]),datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[2]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[3](datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[4]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[5]]),(datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[6]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[7]]),(datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[8]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[9]]),(datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[10]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[11]]),(datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[12]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[13]]),(datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[14]],datum_points[crossPart_datums_keys[15]]))
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: what version? You should check the scripting manual for your specific version as the keywords have been known to change.

Comment: I am using Abaqus Version 6.14.

Comment: could be you haven't loaded the module that defines OFF. You should have `from abaqusConstants import*` at the top of the script. Also make sure you haven't used OFF as a variable someplace else.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/40528448/1004168

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Abaqus 6.14 Scripting Reference Guide, `WirePolyLine` has two arguments, `points` and `mergeType`. `mergeWire` and `meshable` are not listed as arguments. Perhaps you should use:

```
from abaqusConstants import SEPARATE
myPart.WirePolyLine(points = myPoints, mergeType = SEPARATE)
```

I strongly suggest you consult section 37.2.56 of Abaqus 6.14 Scripting Reference Guide.

Comment: well there you go. in the 6.11 manual there is `mergeWire` and not `mergeType`.