# Warning of NameError for wireType in ABAQUS

Tags: python, nameerror, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I tried to connect points through wires using script. A warning regarding the NameError occurred.

the code i tried to run in abaqus:

```
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
v11 = a.instances['r-mesh-2'].vertices
v12 = a.instances['s-mesh-1'].vertices
v13 = a.instances['r-mesh-1'].vertices
v14 = a.instances['s-mesh-1-lin-2-1'].vertices
a.WirePolyLine(points=((v11.findAt(coordinates=(2.595, 0.22, -35.7)), 
    v12.findAt(coordinates=(2.595, 0.2, -35.7))), (v11.findAt(coordinates=(
    2.445, 0.22, -35.7)), v12.findAt(coordinates=(2.445, 0.2, -35.7))), (
    v13.findAt(coordinates=(1.095, 0.22, -35.7)), v12.findAt(coordinates=(
    1.095, 0.2, -35.7))), (v13.findAt(coordinates=(0.945, 0.22, -35.7)), 
    v12.findAt(coordinates=(0.945, 0.2, -35.7))), (v11.findAt(coordinates=(
    2.595, 0.22, -35.1)), v14.findAt(coordinates=(2.595, 0.2, -35.1)))), 
    mergeType=IMPRINT, meshable=OFF)
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
e1 = a.edges
edges1 = e1.findAt(((2.595, 0.215, -35.1), ), ((0.945, 0.215, -35.7), ), ((
    1.095, 0.215, -35.7), ), ((2.445, 0.215, -35.7), ), ((2.595, 0.215, -35.7), 
    ))
a.Set(edges=edges1, name='Wire-1-Set-1')
```

Here's the error:
NameError: name 'IMPRINT' is not defined

Another time I purposefully changed that part of the code as 'mergeType='IMPRINT', then the error becomes:
TypeError: mergeType; found string, expecting IMPRINT, MERGE or SEPARATE

How to solve the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module giving you the error is expecting a certain constant from another module. Import the module with the necessary constants:

```
from abaqusConstants import *
```

Then use `mergeType=IMPRINT, ...` as you are already doing. Or you could avoid polluting your namespace and alias it instead:

```
import abaqusConstants as ac
```

And then use `mergeType=ac.IMPRINT, ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm new to ABAQUS and Python, there can be lots of basics that I'm not aware of. So I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. I saved the first part of the code as a new file: ab.py. Then execute <import abaqusConstants as ab>. And then use mergeType=ab.IMPRINT, ...  Now I get the error <mergeType=ab.IMPRINT, meshable=OFF
TypeError: 'AbaqusBoolean' object is not iterable>. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Solved! put < from abaqusConstants import * > at the top of the code...

Comment: I'm glad to hear that this answer solved the problem. You can mark it as such for future users by clicking the check mark below its score to accept it.